# I just upgraded by Raspberry PI 400 to 64bit. The screens no longer go into sleep mode. I know next little about linux so please make few assumptions

Tags: hdmi, display, raspberry-pi-os, 64-bit

I just upgraded my Raspberry PI 400 to 64bit. The screens no longer go into sleep mode.
I know next to nothing about linux so if you know a fix please make as few assumptions as possible.

Comment: `upgraded my Raspberry PI 400 to 64bit` ... what exactly did you do?

Comment: I used Imager to download and install the 64-bit full version of the Raspberry Pi OS.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi's don't really have a power management system baked in (see: https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=243421) so there is no real 'sleep mode'. Do you maybe mean that the screen goes blank? (Aka, a screen saver?)

If so, have you tried enabling it in the Raspberry Pi configuration screen? `sudo raspi-config` -> `2. Display Options` -> `D4. Screen Blanking?`

Or maybe install a screensaver application? Like: `xscreensaver`. I believe you can download it from the GUI's software center, or from the terminal with `sudo apt install xscreensaver`

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's a new command to me. Thanks. I found something yesterday that sort of did the trick except the task bar would jump displays when the displays came back on. Hopefully this will overwrite that as I've already forgot what I did. If this doesn't work I might go back to 32-bit as I think I've made it unstable.

Comment: If you are going for stability and consistency, do use 32-bit. The 64-bit version of Raspbian still does not have a LTS release. Almost every program for the Raspberry Pi's have been written with 32bits in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have unstablized the OS. So I've gone back to the 32-bit backup I made at the start. I only wanted 64-bit for the supposed speed increase but 32-bit is fine by me.

Comment: There is no "speed increase" you have to run artificial benchmarks to see any difference.